# How do I create a VHD of XP laptop to work In windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization

I found a program called disk2VHD and createa VHD of
my XP laptop but when I try run it Windows 7 it does not
start.
Just some text scrolls up but can't read it quick enough.

Any ideas if there is another program to create VHD for win7?

Malcolm

Comment: What virtualization program are you using within windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/get.html). It can convert physical machines to virtual machines and supports hot cloning (make the vm while you're on the physical machine itself, just like disk2vhd). Any virtual machine it creates will work with their products. I recommend [VMware Server](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/) as it is free and allows you to create and run virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

The XP machine's HAL is configured for the physical hardware it came from. You have to install the appropriate Virtual Hardware drivers and configure XP to detect the new HAL before shutting XP down, then image the machine, and the image will boot under Virtual PC.

The drivers and integration components can be found in an ISO file installed wtih Virtual PC in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Virtual PC\Integration Components\IntegrationComponents.iso`. After that's installed run `msconfig`, on the Boot tab click the Advanced button, then check "Detect HAL". After that you should be able to shutdown the PC and image it to a VHD file.

(There is a chance your install of XP is missing certain drivers, this will cause a BSOD STOP x7B, when you boot the VM. The solution is to expand atapi.sys, intelide.sys, pciide.sys, and pciidex.sys from the WinXP CD i386 folder into the System32 folder before imaging the XP machine.)

Answer (score 0):

The vitual pc for windows 7 is limited at best.  You can still use that image with something called VMWARE.  Or if you like, In the settings of the vitual pc you can add a image file to the cdrom device.  with this image(winxp.iso/or other) you can install any version you like.  VMWARE has more options that will work with more formats.

Comment: The Virual PC for Win7 is no more limited than previous versions, and actuales comes with software for RemoteApp as well. The configuration options however are more 'hidden' than in previous verions of the software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VHD that you generated with Disk2vhd without any problem.

**What's missing is the Virtual Machine!**

Start the `New Virtual Machine Wizard` of Microsoft's Virtual PC, and give your VHD file when it asks for the hard disk, and your VM is done.

Comment: I have run the wizard but it still doesn't start.

Comment: Astounding. Do you get an error message?

Comment: Some text scrolls but too quick then window goes black.

Comment: Then probably something went wrong with the vhd. Try John T's suggestion for VMware Converter. It and VMware Player are free.